# NLog MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped for multiple keys

Tags: .net, nlog

When handling messages from a queue, I'd like to track multiple parameters for each message - its id, user_name, etc.
Based on my findings `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped` should work, is there any way to set several keys at once? The number of such fields varies based on known conditions, so I'd like a helper that sets all the fields at once.
Current API doesn't allow composition, unfortunately, so the following attempt fails:

```
    public static IDisposable SetContext(this Dictionary<string, string> fieldValues)
    {
        IDisposable result = null;

        foreach (var pair in fieldValues)
        {
            result = MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This method removes only the last added key, all the previous ones stay there.
Underlying API's of `SetScoped` method are internal to NLog, so I can't easily call them.
Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to NLog ver. 4.6.5 will allow you to use this method:

```
IDisposable MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped(IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string,object>> items);
```

You can call it like this:

```
MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped(fieldValues);
```

But your fieldValues must be of the type `Dictionary<string, object>`